# How to remove an element from ajax response before appending?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX that works fine. But there is a certain HTML element that I will need to completely remove before appending the AJAX response to my page.

My AJAX code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url-to-the-site.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success: function(data){

        for( x in data ){
        var articles = data[x].html;

        console.log(articles);

           $(".appender").before(articles);

        } 

    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

So, the variable `articles` has an element/tag called `<footer>`.

I need to completely remove this BEFORE appending the `articles`.

I tried this in my for each in my AJAX but I know this is wrong:

```
$(articles).find('footer').remove();
```

Could someone please advice on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about jQuery, but I can try and solve it in pure JavaScript.

1. You haven't provided enough content to decide the datatype of articles.
   But from what I see, 'articles' is a string, hence you can't call DOM functions on it.

I'd try using a regular expression to remove the footer from the articles string.

Here is my attempt at it:

```
var example = "<article><p>Foo Bar</p><footer>Foo Bar</footer></article>";
var formatted = example.replace(/<footer>.*<\/footer>/, "");
console.log(formatted);
```

Output:

```
<article><p>Foo Bar</p></article>
```

Put the code above in the loop before you apped it to the DOM.

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url-to-the-site.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {},
    success: function(data){

    for( x in data ){
    var articles = data[x].html;

       $(".appender").before(articles.replace(/<footer>.*<\/footer>/, ""));

    } 

},
error: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

});

[Updated]

To cater for newlines and other characters:

`var formatted = example.replace(/<footer.*>(.|[\n\r])*<\/footer>/, "");`

Comment: My example didn't include newline characters in the articles string. I have updated it as such